# Want to convert a simple html page into wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Actually i want to convert a simple html page into a wordpress plugin. Can anyone help me, How could i achieve this. However I can use wordpress and install plugins in it. Is there a simple way to do this. My HTML page just conatins a simple html form.

Answer (score 0):

```
For converting html pages to wordpress pages.u can follow the below steps:
1.Copy the contents of ur home page to home.php(create an empty home.php file in ur  
  wordpress root directory).Then delete if any other home.php file in the theme exists.
2.Likewise,if u want to create another page,then,copy the related contents for that 
  page(for eg aboutus),then create new aboutus.php and paste contents in it.
3.Run ur wordpress blog or site to feel the changes.
```

Answer (score -1):

So. You have a html page with a form in it, and want to display it trough aplugin. If you want to show that on page, you should create a shortcode within your plugin. Once activated, the shortcode will be active. Paste the shortcode and only the shortcode in the content of a new page.